# portlet (JSF) with ajax - Websphere Portal 7, RAD 8

Tags: ajax, jsf, websphere, portlet, portal

I want created a portlet (JSF) with ajax but doesn't render.

The example I tried this example of IBM http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/06/1205_kats_rad2/, but not run in WebSphere Portal only in WAS. (New Dynamic Web Project)
I search in many forums, and solution is change "Classloader mode" from "PARENT_FIRST" to "PARENT_LAST", i cant find this Classloader in project file, I tried change in server but a wasn't work.

Please give me a simple example who I created a portlet JSF with AJAX or who change Classloader mode to resolve this problem.

Greetings, João Sousa

Answer (score 0):

Joao,

in project/package explorer right click on J2EE and select Open WebSphere Application Server Deployment. Deployment settings editor will be opened. Now scroll down to Application section. Now you can switch between PARENT_LAST & PARENT_FIRST.

Bogdan.